# Tkinter not recognizing any type of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
tk.geometry("500x300")

def submitFunction() :
  q1 = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
  q1.pack


button_submit = tkinter.Button(tk, text ="Submit", command=submitFunction)
button_submit.config(width=20, height=2)

button_submit.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

As you can see by running the code and editing the variable `q1` to any other function it will not work, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Label'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__    
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Bristol Virginia Public Schools\Desktop\Current projects\main.py", line 8, in submitFunction
    q1 = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
  File "C:\Users\tpitcock\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2383, in __getattr__ 
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Label'
```

I tried changing text to different things but it didn't work.

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Typo: `tk` is the `Tk` object. `tkinter` is the module. `tk.Label` should be `tkinter.Label`, just as you did in `tkinter.Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you what is wrong. It says that `tk` doesn't have an attribute named `Label`, which is true. In your code, `tk` isn't the tkinter module, it's the instance of `Tk` that you created with this line:

```
tk = tkinter.Tk(className='Tkinter - TutorialKart', )
```

If you want to use the tkinter `Label` class, it needs to come from the `tkinter` module just like you do with `tkinter.Tk` and `tkinter.Button`:

```
q1 = tkinter.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
#    ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -2):

what is your goal? Do you just want to make a window? If yes, first you need to import all of the classes in tkinter with `from tkinter import *`. And after that you can make an object from **Tk** class: `Favorite name = Tk()`. Then you can access all functions and classes in tkinter using this object. The code below is a simple design of a window:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("your favorite")
window.geometry("700x700")
.
.
.
window.mainloop()
```